# Setting up python path inside python

Tags: python

Let's say I have a python package called `my project`. Inside this directory, I have two other directories named `run_files` and `code_files`. So the file structure is as follows:

```
->my project
      |
      |___________
      |           ->run_files
      |                |
      |                |_________run.py
      |
      |___________
                  -> code_files
                       |
                       |_________codes.py
```

As the names suggests `run_files` contains the python file (like `run.py`) where I am going to execute my python program while `code_files` contains other files (like `code.py`) where the main codes of my program exist. Clearly, I need to import some of the files inside the `code_files` directory to run my program.

However, the problem is that because of this structure I get `import error` since when python wants to run it, it looks into the parent directory and tries to find the files with root `run_files`. How can I change this with a code inside my python file `run.py` instead of resorting to changing it on terminal.

Comment: I suggest restructuring your code slightly. Put the script you intend to run directly under `my project`, and have it import code you need from `run_files`. Your actual script may be no more than `import run_files; run_files.run.go()`, where `run.go` is just your script-level code wrapped in a function to serve as an entry point.

Comment: Any reason not to create it as an actual module package and install it with `-e` (editable)?

Comment: If any of the answers solved your question, it's good practice to upvote and accept. The latter also grants you a small rep bonus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to access any file on your computer is probably `sys.path`

```
# code_file.py
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'location/of/code_files')

import code_file
```

You can also use `append()` instead of `insert()`:

```
sys.path.append('location/of/code_files')
```

Comment: Hi @alec935, I need to test it on my server to see it works. Thanks for answering. If it solves my problem then sure I am going to accept and up vote it. Please wait till tomorrow.

Comment: No problem! I just like leaving that comment because people forget :)